# Why Is Sudo Using 908kib of Memory

Tags: sudo, root, ram, memory-usage

I ran the following command.

```
sudo sleep 100000
```

Then, I checked the memory usage of the sudo process. Sudo is using **908KiB** of private memory and **4.2MiB** of shared memory. I know it's not a problem with the Linux Kernel enforcing a minimum memory working set because, for example, the bpfilter_umh process uses only 60KiB of private memory and the sd-spam process uses only 4KiB of shared memory. Even if it somehow takes sudo an absurd amount of memory to elevate a process, sudo should be able to release that memory back to the system after it is done elevating the process.

This is a problem with, for example, running many user sessions on the same computer, each running several commands via sudo. It is also a problem for deeply nested sudo commands, where a script is called with sudo that then calls successive scripts with sudo.

So, what is going on with sudo? Why does it take such an excessive amount of memory to do something as small as elevating the process?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask states "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here." So, please tell us what problem this makes for you.

Comment: @K7AAY This is a problem with, for example, running many user sessions on the same computer, each running several commands via sudo. It is also a problem for deeply nested sudo commands, where a script is called with sudo that then calls successive scripts with sudo.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529356/70524

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote?